# Button title text doesn't clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I have `BtnDate` Button , when clicked, action works and gets current date with popup and adding inside `BtnDate.titleLabel.text` and when I use inside my `btnAddForm` action to check if `_myText` is bigger than `> 0` clear `_BtnDate.titleLabel.text`

But it doesn't clear the `titleLabel` text string.

My code is below.

I want, if the user entry `_myText` inside > 0 value for `_BtnDate` to be empty.

My entire code is below:

.h file inside:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton* BtnDate;
```

.m file inside:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


         [_BtnDate addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         _BtnDate.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        [[_BtnDate layer] setBorderWidth:1];
        [[_BtnDate layer] setCornerRadius:5];
        [[_BtnDate layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        [_BtnDate setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:_BtnDate];


    }


    -(void) showDateView{

        viewBack2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        [viewBack2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
        [self.view addSubview:viewBack2];


        dateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((viewBack2.frame.size.width-300)/2, (viewBack2.frame.size.height-350)/2, 300, 350)];
        [self.view addSubview:dateView];

        UIImageView *imageBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-popup"]];
        [imageBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 350)];
        [dateView addSubview:imageBackground];
        [imageBackground release];

        UIButton *BtnDate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [BtnDate setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"okay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [BtnDate addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDateAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [BtnDate setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 300, 140, 36)];
        [dateView addSubview:BtnDate];


        datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,25, 250, 250)];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

        datePicker.hidden = NO;
        datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
        [datePicker addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [dateView addSubview:datePicker];



    }


    - (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender{

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        if (_BtnDate.selected==true) {
            [_BtnDate setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        [df release];
    }


    -(IBAction)btnDateAction:(id)sender{

        if (_BtnDate.selected==true) {
            _BtnDate.selected=false;
        }

        [dateView removeFromSuperview];
        [viewBack2 removeFromSuperview];


    }



    - (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {

        if (sender == _BtnDate) {

            [self showDateView];
            _BtnDate.selected=true;
        }


    }


    - (IBAction)btnAddForm:(id)sender {


    // I WANT TO CHECK _myText if is not null or > 0 must be clear _BtnDate.titleLabel.text  dont do this !


     if ([NSNumber numberWithInt:[_myText.text intValue]] > 0 )  {

            _BtnDate.titleLabel.text = @"";


      }
}


    - (void)dealloc {
        [_myText release];
        [_BtnDate release];
        [super dealloc];
    }
    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        [self setmyText:nil];
        [self setBtnDate:nil];
        [super viewDidUnload];
    }
```

Comment: @Rajat where i will add it ? ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you click on `btnAddForm`

set this

```
[BtnDate setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need to specify ControlState when updating button's title! There are four possible values for UIButtons:

```
UIControlStateNormal
UIControlStateHighlighted
UIControlStateDisabled
UIControlStateSelected
```

So Try this

```
[BtnDate setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

In showDateView you use a local variable BtnDate to create your button and install it in your dateView. As a result the `BtnDate` property is probably nil.

Change your code that creates the button to use the instance variable.

```
_BtnDate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_BtnDate setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"okay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_BtnDate addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDateAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_BtnDate setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 300, 140, 36)];
[dateView addSubview:_BtnDate];
```

By the way, properties and other variable names should start with a lower-case letter, so `BtnDate` should be `btnDate`.